# Как сформировать разный код для разных build variants в Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio

В зависимости от варианта билда можно использовать конструкции вида

```
if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
        Timber.plant(Timber.DebugTree())
    }
```

Как переписать конструкцию

```
  private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
        //.client(client) убрать в release
        .baseUrl("https://example.net/")
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
        .build()
```

чтобы строка .client(client) входила в дебажный билд, и не входила в релиз? 
Может есть какие то варианты с Gradle или ProGuard?

Comment: Можно убрать полностью, но будет 2 реализации одного класса (два файла). Если такое устроит, я отвечу.

Comment: Нет, тогда уж проще внести в условие весь билдер : private val retrofit =  if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {Retrofit.Builder()
  .client(client)
        .baseUrl("https://example.net/")
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .build()   
    }
 else {Retrofit.Builder()
        .baseUrl("https://example.net/")
        .addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        .build()   
 }   Но хотелось бы в условии иметь только строку с  .client

Comment: понятно, но учтите что ваш код войдет обе версии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте scope-функцию `apply`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/scope-functions.html#apply

```
private val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder().apply {
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) client(client)
        baseUrl("https://example.net/")
        addConverterFactory(MoshiConverterFactory.create(moshi))
        addCallAdapterFactory(CoroutineCallAdapterFactory())
    }.build()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]